# In React, how to get the ID of a dropdown when the dropdown value changes?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

With the below code, I am rendering a table with a few color dropdowns in it. When on of the color dropdowns change, I would like to obtain the ID of the dropdown that changed.

Any suggestions?

```
handleColorChange(e, key) {
    console.log(key) // logs the orange/blue/black

}

renderDropdown(color, myId) {
    const statuses = ["orange", "blue", "black"];
    const menuItems = statuses.map((option, index) =>
        <MenuItem
            key={index}
            id={`type-${option}`}
            eventKey={option}
            active={option === color}
        >
            {option}
        </MenuItem>,
    );

    return (
        <Dropdown id={myId} bsStyle="primary" onSelect={(e, key) => this.handleColorChange(e, key)}>
            <Dropdown.Toggle>
                {status}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                {menuItems}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}

renderDropdown(orange, 1);
renderDropdown(blue, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass anything you want to `handleColorChange` and in your case, you already have access to `myId`. Pass that to the function and you're good to go!

```
e => this.handleColorChange(e,myId)
```

Comment: oh! when I tried that I messed up the variable scoping, so I got `undefinied`. this works, thanks!